# How to add sub-sets of grouped information as one group?

Tags: lists, hierarchy, grouped-list

*Trying to describe this as best as possible,* we have a group of 3 pieces of information (1 x label, 1 x text area, 1 x label) alongside a " submit and add new "button. Once submitted, the submitted information is added and the user repeats the process 4 to 5 times. The user then submits that overall information (Therefore containing of 5 sub-sets of information).

Imagine it being similar to adding multiple addresses into a mini-address book and then saving that mini-address book. i.e. the user adds a name, an address, and a phone number, submits it to the address book, repeats this process numerous times, then saves that entire address book.

Can anyone think of a similar problem how other companies address this? Is there a recommended solution for this problem?

[image]

(Possible duplicate but not quite accurate: [Grouped list with a lot of singletons -- how to present groups of size one?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10967/grouped-list-with-a-lot-of-singletons-how-to-present-groups-of-size-one))

Comment: Is your content all or nothing (all of it is stored at once or none of it is)?  Is the user allowed to come back later and add more items to the group?

Comment: It's all and no, they cannot return to the content. I might provide a real life example to help the matter out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JIRA is a bug and project tracking software that many in the IT and project management field should be familar with.  In JIRA, user is able to Create Issue in a pop up light-box:

[image]

JIRA provide a check-box option to allow user to create multiple issues without leaving the light-box.

[image]

This is how it works:

1. Fill in the fields for current issue
2. Check the "Create another" box
3. Click on Create
4. The issue you've just created is saved and this
   light-box emptys and is ready to recieve data from user to create
   another issue.
5. If user is done creating issues, simply uncheck the
   checkbox and click on Create to create the last issue.

I have found this solution to be very user friendly.

Comment: Essentially they take the user away from the page to concentrate on the current objective, and then return them back to the page to see a summary of their selected data? Nice. Good idea.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The light-box will not dismiss until  user has finished creating an issue or group of issues.